# Лучший способ инжекта скрипта в Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Задача: из background-скрипта получить код в текстовом представлении и добавить его в окно браузера как можно быстрее и в то же время чтобы это отработало.

Вот пример:

```
var i = localStorage;
var code = "console.log('Hello')";

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (c, changeInfo) {
    i['tab' + c] ? ++i['tab' + c] : i['tab' + c] = 1;

    if (i['tab' + c] == 1) {
        (function (с, code) {

            var s = code.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");

            chrome.tabs.executeScript(с, {
                    code: '(function(){var scr = document.createElement("script"); scr.textContent = `' + s  + '`; (document.body || document.head).appendChild(scr);})();'
               });
            };
        })(с, code);

});

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function (c) {
    delete i['tab' + c];
});

chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function (c) {
    (c['frameId'] === 0) ? (delete i['tab' + c['tabId']]) : void 0;
});

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function (details) {
    var c = details.tabId;
    localStorage['tab' + c] ? void 0 : localStorage['tab' + c] = 0;
});
```

Этот пример работает, но дважды инжектит скрипт, если уже открыто окно, и расширение устанавливается позже, чем открыто окно.

Answer (score 0):

Многократный инжект скрипта связан с использованием события `onUpdated`. 
Попробуйте поэксперементировать с [chrome.tabs.onCreated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated).

А вообще для выполнения кода на странице отлично подходит [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), у которого, к тому же, можно указать точку старта исполения (поле `run_at`)